# Recall ListItem value/variable in another Activity

Tags: java, android

as in image I've a listView of flags (for example). When I click one of this in 2nd Activity I get the text name and medium image of this flag. all work fine and as I wanted. But now in 2nd Activity when I click on the image I would like to see the respective Big Image on the 3th Activity but I can not do it. How I can do?

[activitys screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iol9C.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
ListView mListView;

String [] Names = {"France", "Germany", "Italy", "USA"};
int [] Small = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4};
int [] Medium = {R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.c2, R.drawable.c3, R.drawable.c4};
int [] Big = {R.drawable.f1, R.drawable.f2, R.drawable.f3, R.drawable.f4};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, Names, Small);
    mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("flagName", Names[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("flagSmall", Small[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("flagMedium", Medium[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("flagBig", Big[i]);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

this is how call the images on 2nd Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureObject;

TextView mTextView;
ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (mBundle != null)
    {
        mImageView.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("flagMedium"));
        mTextView.setText(mBundle.getString("flagName"));
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a class called `public class Country { private String name; private int smallFlag; private int mediumFlag; private int bigFlag;`, make it parcelable, and send that through the bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my simple solution with **mIndex**:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureObject;

TextView mTextView;
ImageView mImageView;
int mIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (mBundle != null)
{
    mImageView.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("flagMedium"));
    mTextView.setText(mBundle.getString("flagName"));
    mIndex = mBundle.getInt("flagBig");
}
```

and I've send the value with intent to other activity.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("fullImg", mIndex);
                startActivity(mIntent);
```